# Thread blocked waiting message

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets, pthreads

I have a *pthread* running and waiting for messages from a socket. The thread gets blocked to wait a message and doesn't wake up until receiving a new one. Is there a way to send a signal to thread to wake up and for the receive function (*recvmsg*) to return an error code related to signal?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, by default SIGINT will interrupt all syscalls. From `man recv`:

```
    EINTR  The receive was interrupted by delivery of a signal before any 
           data were available; see signal(7). 
and 
    MSG_WAITALL (since Linux 2.2)
          This flag requests that the operation block until the full request is 
          satisfied.  However, the call may still return less data than requested
          if a signal is caught, an error or disconnect occurs, or the next 
          data to be received is of a different type than that returned.
```

However, you cannot target a specific thread or specific operation.

If you wish to have this, I suggest using a condition that the receiving thread can explicitely listen for. There is a wellknown trick on linux which allows the receiving thread to use `select` or `poll` to *listen* for the socket **and** the 'condition' simultaneously[1].

The trick is to open a pipe from the master thread to the client (receiving) thread. The master writes to the pipe upon reaching a certain state (the signal so to speak). The client (receiving) thread can simply poll both the pipe *and* the socket and only check which of the two awoke it.

---

[1] *normally `pthread_cond_wait` and `poll`/`select` cannot be combined without racing so you'd need to program wait loops with small timeouts. On Win32 by contrast it is as simple as `WaitForMultipleObjects` and you're done*

Comment: pthread_kill lets you send a signal to a thread, but I would prefer the pipe-solution anyway

Comment: nice hint. didn't know about pthread_kill; the man page says the whole process can be affected tho,YMMV (updating the answer with the man page excerpt)

Comment: I should note about pthread_kill that for SIGINT it should affect the targeted thread.  It's not surprising that STOP/CONTINUE/TERM would affect all threads (in linux/Unix)

Comment: if you want to use blocking IO then the only option to cancel them is via signals. if you are using nonblocking IO, then you should inpect why you need threads, and how you use them. the number of threads should be kept close to the number of CPUs, per connection threading models do not scale.